# Echo multiple values from a single database entry after LEFT JOIN to pull names from a different table

Tags: php, sql

I hope the title makes sense and sorry if this is a duplicate I wasn't certain what to search for to find the correct answer.

I have a table on a website that pulls info from a database. So my issue is I have two tables in the database, the_traveler and the_discipline. What I am doing is pulling the value from the traveler that looks like this 89,43 and after I LEFT JOIN with the_disciplines table, to get the name that correlates with the numbers, like so:

```
 $query ="SELECT t.name,t.traveler_id, t.disciplines, dis.name as discname

 FROM ".TABLEPRIFIX."traveler t
 LEFT JOIN ".TABLEPRIFIX."discipline dis ON t.disciplines = dis.id";

 $disname = $obj->queryResult($query);
```

I am only able to echo out the first numbers name by doing this:

```
<?php
foreach($disname as $traveler) 
{
<tr>
<td><?php echo $traveler['discname']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

My question is how would I change my code to get all the numbers from the database to echo in each row. I have tried to implode the numbers.

Comment: I think you didn't copy/paste the entire query... you dont have a select anywhere.

Comment: @Brds you're right thank you I added it in.

Comment: Could you post an example output (just text or html) to clarify what are you expecting to display?

Comment: @F.Igor what I am trying to get for the output would be the names (from the_discipline table that match the numbers from the_traveler table) so an example would be "nurse doctor" but right now I am only able to print out "nurse" however when I try to just print out the numbers both show up.

Comment: So there is more than one discipline for each traveler. Is `t.disciplines` a multi-value field or multiple-row? Could you post some example rows of each table?

Comment: Yeah the discipline column for each traveler can have multiple numbers. The t.disciplines row is a longtext and an example on one column is 89,43. The numbers are the id's from the disciplines table and that table contains the names that I am trying to get, which I am accomplishing it just isn't printing out both names just the first numbers name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a single row with all values you must change the code to:

```
<tr>
<?php
foreach($disname as $traveler) 
{
<td><?php echo $traveler['discname']; ?></td>
<?php
}
?>   
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm basically printing out the database so I need multiple rows but each rows discipline can have multiple values (names).